# How to pass around parameter packs in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Consider the following example:

```
template <class T> class method_traits;
template <class T, class Ret, class... Arg> class method_traits<Ret(T::*)(Arg...)> {
public:
    using type = Arg; // this does not work
};

template <class T> using argument_types = typename method_traits<T>::type;

template <class T> class Node {
    T t;
public:
    Node(Input<argument_types<decltype(&T::process)>>... inputs) { // how do I make this work?
        ...
    }
};
```

The arguments of the constructor of `Node<T>` depend on the arguments of the method `T::process`. So if a type `T` has a method `process` of the signature `float process(float a, int b)` the signature of the constructor of `Node<T>` should look like this: `Node(Input<float> a, Input<int> b)`.

How do I extract the parameter pack from `T::process` to use it on the constructor of `Node`?

Comment: You need to make Node a variadic template too.

Comment: @n.m. but `Node` only depends on a single type `T` and not on multiple types

Comment: @n.m. Surely it suffices to make Node's constructor a variadic template, rather than the whole class?

Comment: @ArthurTacca it could be, depending on what Node is storing.

Comment: In my case `Node` stores the `Input`s in a tuple so I guess making the constructor a variadic template would work.

Comment: You cannot say "my member function will have the same signature as T::somefunction. It's a deficiency in C++ syntax. To overcome it, you need to introduce an artificial parameter pack that doesn't express any real dependency.

Comment: What's `Input`? Is that important to the question?

Comment: Note most of the answers will fail if the member function has cv-qualifiers, has ref-qualifiers, or is C-style variadic, (or in C++17, is noexcept). See the ugly sample definition of `std::is_function` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function for a hint on how it would need to be done properly.

Comment: @Barry It is not important to the question. It is just there to show that the arguments are not exactly the same but depend on each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously you can't save a list of types in this way

```
    using type = Arg;
```

where `Arg` is a variadic list of types.

But you can save they in a type container and `std::tuple` can do this works too. So I suggest to modify the `method_traits` specialization as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct method_traits;

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct method_traits<Ret(T::*)(Args...)>
 { using tTypes = std::tuple<Args...>; };
```

and rewrite `argument_types` to intercept the `std::tuple`

```
template <typename T>
using tTypes = typename method_traits<T>::tTypes;
```

Now you can use the default template value and partial specialization trick defining node

```
template <typename T, typename TArgs = tTypes<decltype(&T::process)>>
struct Node;
```

In this way, instantiating a `Node<T>` object, you effectively get a `Node<T, tTypes<decltype(&T::process)>` that is a `Node<T, std::tuple<Args...>>` with the wanted `Args...`.

So you can simply define the following partial specialization of `Node` as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct Node<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
 {
   T t;

   Node (Input<Args> ... inputs)
    { /* do something */ }
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct tWrapper
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using Input = typename tWrapper<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct method_traits;

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct method_traits<Ret(T::*)(Args...)>
 { using tTypes = std::tuple<Args...>; };

template <typename T>
using tTypes = typename method_traits<T>::tTypes;

template <typename T, typename TArgs = tTypes<decltype(&T::process)>>
struct Node;

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct Node<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
 {
   T t;

   Node (Input<Args> ... inputs)
    { /* do something */ }
 };

struct foo
 {
   float process (float a, int b)
    { return a+b; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Node<foo> nf(1.0f, 2);
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Julius (and the OP themselves) this solution require an additional template type with a default template value.

In this simplified case isn't a problem but I can imagine circumstances where this additional template argument can't be added (by example: if `Node` receive a variadic list of template arguments).

In those cases, Julius propose a way that complicate a little the solution but permit to avoid the additional  template parameter for `Node`: to add a template base class, that receive the `TArgs` arguments, and to works with constructor inheritance.

That is: defining a `NodeBase` as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct NodeBase;

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct NodeBase<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
 {
   T t;

   NodeBase (Input<Args> ...)
    { /* do something */ }
 };
```

there is no need for an additional template parameter, for `Node`, that can simply written as

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
   : public NodeBase<T, tTypes<decltype(&T::process)>>
 { using NodeBase<T, tTypes<decltype(&T::process)>>::NodeBase; };
```

Julius, following this idea, prepared [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876852/6022656) that (IMHO) is even better and interesting.

Comment: nice solution, even though it requires to add a second template parameter to `Node`

Comment: @eyelash - yes; but the second parameter is a default one; so, as you can see in `main()`, you can instantiate a `Node` simply as `Node<foo>`.

Comment: Very nice solution. If that default template parameter is not acceptable, one could derive from a base class with constructor inheritance.

Comment: @Julius - thanks; I prefer the default template type way, but I can imagine circumstances where it's an impracticable solution. In that circumstances, your idea can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using perfect forwarding ([live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e077fb85a28c2460)):

```
template<typename... Args>
Node(Args&&... args) {
    process(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Honestly this is the answer, all the answers above are needlessly convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example in C++11 (thanks to max66's comment) based on [max66's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876743/2615118). The differences here:

- no additional template argument for `Node` (instead, using a base class and constructor inheritance)
- the desired arguments are obtained with a slightly different style than shown in the question

  - adding overloads for qualified member functions is simple
  - references are not a problem (as far as I can tell; see example below printing `42`)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53c23e1e9774490c

```
#include <iostream>

template<class... Ts> struct Types {};

template<class R, class C, class... Args>
constexpr Types<Args...> get_argtypes_of(R (C::*)(Args...)) {
    return Types<Args...>{};
}

template<class R, class C, class... Args>
constexpr Types<Args...> get_argtypes_of(R (C::*)(Args...) const) {
    return Types<Args...>{};
}

template<class T, class ConstructorArgs>
struct NodeImpl;

template<class T, class Arg0, class... Args>
struct NodeImpl<T, Types<Arg0, Args...>> {
  NodeImpl(Arg0 v0, Args...) {
    v0 = typename std::decay<Arg0>::type(42);
    (void)v0;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct Node
  : NodeImpl<T, decltype(get_argtypes_of(&T::process))>
{
  using ConstructorArgs = decltype(get_argtypes_of(&T::process));
  using NodeImpl<T, ConstructorArgs>::NodeImpl;
};

struct Foo {
    void process(int, char, unsigned) const {}
};

struct Bar {
    void process(double&) {}
};

int main() {
    Node<Foo> foo_node{4, 'c', 8u};

    double reftest = 2.0;
    Node<Bar> bar_node{reftest};
    std::cout << reftest << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Also your's is a nice solution; if you want it to works with C++11, it's very simple: avoid to return `auto` in `get_argtypes_of()` and explicit that return a `Types<Args...>`. If you're worried for the repetition of `Types<Args...>`, you can simply `return {};`. (continue)

Comment: And, considering that you use `get_argtypes_of()` only in a couple of `decltypes()` (because you're only interested in returned type, non in returned value) you can also declare it and not implement it (as `std::declval()`); I mean that it's enough `template<class R, class C, class... Args>
constexpr auto get_argtypes_of(R (C::*)(Args...));`, without the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using C++14. (Note: I have only tested it in clang, though):

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
    void process(int, std::string);
};

template <typename T>
struct Input { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename ...Types>
struct Extract_type {
    using type = typename Extract_type<N - 1, Types...>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Types>
struct Extract_type<0, T, Types...> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename R, typename ...Args>
typename Extract_type<N, Args...>::type extract(R (T::*)(Args...));

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)> num_args(R (T::*)(Args...));

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    template <typename ...Args>
    Node(Input<Args>&&... args) 
    : Node(std::make_index_sequence<decltype(num_args<T>(&T::process))::value>{ }, std::forward<Input<Args>>(args)...)
    {}

    template <std::size_t ...Indices>
    Node(std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Input<decltype(extract<T, Indices>(&T::process))>...) {}
};


int main() {
    Node<Foo> b{ Input<int>{ }, Input<std::string>{ } };
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da7670f80a229931

Answer (score 0):

How about using private inheritance and CRTP?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Method> struct method_traits;

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct method_traits<Ret(T::*)(Args...)> {
public:
    using parameter_pack = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename Derived, typename Tuple> struct Base;

template <typename Derived, typename... Ts>
struct Base<Derived, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    void execute_constructor(Ts&&... ts) { 
        Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        d->t.process(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        d->num = sizeof...(Ts);
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
class Node : Base<Node<T, Rest...>, typename method_traits<decltype(&T::process)>::parameter_pack> {
    T t;
    int num;
public:
    using Base = Base<Node<T, Rest...>, typename method_traits<decltype(&T::process)>::parameter_pack>;
    friend Base;  // So that Base can do whatever it needs to Node<T, Rest...>'s data members.
    template <typename... Ts>
    Node (Ts&&... ts) {
        Base::execute_constructor(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        std::cout << "num = " << num << '\n';
    }
};

struct foo {
    void process(int a, char c, bool b) {
        std::cout << "foo(" << a << ", " << c << ", " << std::boolalpha << b << ") carried out.\n";
    }   
};

int main() {
    Node<foo> n(5, 'a', true);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

```
foo(5, a, true) carried out.
num = 3
```